# как скрыть jsp в папке webapps tomcat'а

Tags: spring, tomcat

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, как скрыть файл jsp из папки WEB-INF в папке webapps на tomcat? Я деплою warник, но когда захожу в папку томката, то у меня там в открытом доступе моя вьюха, ее можно менять и соответственно меняется вид страницы.

Можно ли как-то это избежать? Не смог найти внятного ответа и сам не знаю

Comment: А в чём проблема? Если кто-то имеет доступ к серверу, значит этому кому-то разрешено всё.

Comment: Это понятно, но возможно ли это сделать? скрыть его, то есть, чтобы только в WEB-INF были папки classes и lib? я так понял, что это настраивается на уровне maven в файле pom.xml

Comment: Можно попробовать выполнить предкомпиляцию, но во-первых, возникнет проблема если Tomcat работает под другой версией Java, а во-вторых, Tomcat может отказаться обрабатывать jsp-страницы без их исходных файлов.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду в открытом доступе?

Comment: ну имею ввиду, чтобы когда я зашел в tomcat\webapps\project\WEB-INF, то кроме папок classes, lib и web.xml ничего не было, а фактически у меня там еще jsp файлы. Сейчас у меня они тоже видны. Я просто слышал, что их можно как-то там спрятать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если установить свойство `antiResourceLocking="true"` в `context.xml`, проявится любопытный побочный эффект, предотвращающий перезагрузку JSP. Разработчики считают, что это не [баг](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37668), а [фича](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html), так что можно ожидать, что это сработает.

Ещё в `$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/web.xml` есть сервлет `JspServlet`. У него много параметров (хорошо задокументированных прямо в `web.xml`), но для этой задачи нам нужны `development` (устанавливаем в `true`) и `modificationTestInterval` (устанавливаем в какое-нибудь очень большое число). В такой комбинации Tomcat будет проверять jsp на изменения с очень большим интервалом, что практически можно приравнять к отсутствию таких проверок.

А ещё можно настроить Tomcat, чтобы он не распаковывал war при деплое, указав параметр `unpackWARs="false"` в `server.xml` ([документация](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/host.html)).

Впрочем, если злоумышленник уже проник на сервер и имеет доступ на запись в папку с Томкатом, всё это вам не сильно поможет.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ :)